# JPanel components don't set in the correct position

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, boxlayout

I have a JPanel that has 3 components in it. When I add the JPanel to a JFrame and make the frame visible the component's don't fit in the right place.

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.*;

public class ProgressPanel extends JPanel{
    private final ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar();
    private final JLabel downloadDesc = new JLabel("downloading...");

    public ProgressPanel() {
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this , BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        setBackground(ClientGui.BACKGROUND_COLOR);

        JLabel instructionsLabel = new JLabel("<html>Downloading your requested file. Please stand by, This might take a while<html>");
        instructionsLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 25));
        instructionsLabel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 0, 10, 0));
        instructionsLabel.setForeground(ClientGui.TEXT_COLOR);
        instructionsLabel.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

        downloadDesc.setAlignmentX(JLabel.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
        downloadDesc.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10 , 0 , 0 , 10));

        add(progressBar);
        add(downloadDesc);
        add(instructionsLabel);
    }

    public void setText(String text){
        downloadDesc.setText(text);
    }

    public void fill(){
        progressBar.fill();
    }

    public void setMax(int max) {
        progressBar.setMax(max);
    }

    private static class ProgressBar extends JProgressBar{
        private int max;
        private int currentValue = 0;

        public ProgressBar(){
            setValue(0);
            setStringPainted(true);
        }

        public void fill(){
            currentValue++;

            setValue(calculatePercentage());
        }

        public void setMax(int max) {
            currentValue=0;
            this.max = max;
        }

        private int calculatePercentage(){
            return ((currentValue / max) * 100);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lg4Ny.png]

The JLabel should be at the far right, even without setting a border it still doesn't work.
It even doesn't let me resize the ProgressBar

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [mre]. 2) Add ASCII art or a (link to a) drawing of the intended layout at the minimum size and when made larger by the user.

Comment: Box alignment doesn't work the way you expect. The "right" alignment causes the right edge of the component to be aligned to the center of the space in the panel. Try adding a label the is left aligned and this will be more apparent. Try using a `GridBagLayout`. You can use the `fill` and `anchor` constraints to control alignment. Or you can check out [Relative Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/02/relative-layout/) which works similar to the BoxLayout but allows you to control the component alignment when you set the alignment property of the RelativeLayout to COMPONENT